# Wierd behaviour with getline()

Tags: c++, getline

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;
void test();

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
        test();
    return 0;
}

void test()
{
    string AB;
    getline(cin,AB);
    cout<<AB<<endl;
    printf("ada\n");
}
```

This code is behaving wierdly. When t=1, the getline() statement is not executed at all and goes directly to the printf("ada\n"); statement. when t=2, 'ada' is printed once first and then input is taken once. This problem doesn't occur if i write test() function in the main() function itself. Guys, please execute it and tell me the solution! I am supposed to use getline() in a different problem where this same error is happenning!

Comment: I promise you the `getline` is beng executed. You're failing to do _any_ error checking on it or go on to determine _why_ it's not extracting any characters. Step #1: learn to blame yourself and not a world-famous, standardised library. Step #2: handle left-over newlines.

Comment: Please take a look at the related questions on the right.

Comment: @ Lightness Races in Orbit ...I know it's my mistake. Thst is why i am asking for a solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scanf()` call in main only consumes the number.  It leaves any newline after the number waiting in the input.

It's also not a great idea to mix C style input with C++ style input.  You would be better off using C++ style throughout, and perhaps use `getline()` throughout as well.

For example:

```
int main()
{
    string line;
    int t;
    getline( cin, line );
    sscanf( line.c_str(), "%d", &t );

    // ...
}
```

This code also doesn't do any error checking.  To make it truly bulletproof you ought to add that.

Comment: So if i use, std::cin in place of scanf(), the program would run as desired???

Comment: It's not as simple as _just_ using `std::cin`.  You have to make sure you consume newlines consistently.  Saying `cin >> t` will have the same problem as `scanf("%d", &t)`, in that it won't consume the newline after the number.  Using `getline()` throughout is one way to do that consistently.  There are other ways to tell `cin` to consume the newline as well.  See the related links at the right for many, many discussions on this topic.

Comment: Thanks a lot!...Understood the problem now!